# Inserting title page with image in Rmarkdown to render a pdf document

Tags: r, pdf, markdown, r-markdown

In Rmarkdown, the following sets the context to generate the pdf document:

```
---
title: "My Report"
author: NDE
output:
  pdf_document:
  fig_caption: true
  toc: true
  highlight: kate
---
```

I want to insert a title page with an image, title before table of contents gets printed. Is there a way I can achieve it?

Comment: Check answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29389149/add-image-in-title-page-of-rmarkdown-pdf/32675074#32675074) is a solution using *LaTeX*

Answer (score 12):

For me it worked using LaTeX commands `\clearpage` and `\tableofcontents`:

```
---
title: "image before toc"
output: pdf_document
---

\centering

![Caption](folder/image.png)

\raggedright
\clearpage
\tableofcontents

# header 1
lore ipsum

## header 2
lore ipsum 

## header 3
lore ipsum 

# header 4
```

If you want the table of contents on the title page, just leave `\clearpage` command out.

I included `\centering` and `\raggedright` commands to center the image on the title page but not the text.

Hope that works for you.

Comment: @Next Door Engineer: Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: @Anna, Nope. Haven't gotten to get this route to work.