# How to start page numbering in R Markdown from the second page?

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, page-numbering

I was wondering if there is a way to start page numbering from the second page and/or print page numbers starting from second page in `R Markdown` when creating pdf output?

This would be useful when adding a title page to the document.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you add the titlepage? Please add a minimal example.

Comment: I am following suggestion given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962651/inserting-title-page-with-image-in-rmarkdown-to-render-a-pdf-document)

Comment: It uses latex so search for latex and skip title page number.

Comment: Done and it worked, posted an answer to this. Thank you @TylerRinker

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After receiving useful comments I solved issue by adding `\pagenumbering{gobble}` just before the title and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` after the title page as follows:

```
\pagenumbering{gobble} 
\centerline{\includegraphics[height=2in]{youricon.png}}
\large{TITLE}
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
 ......
 Other chapters of the document
```

Note that this starts numbering from the page after the title, i.e. page number 1 will be printed on the following page after the title page.