# Inserting a blank page after a title page in RMarkdown

Tags: r, pdf, format, latex, r-markdown

I am trying to insert a blank page between the title page and the table of contents in my RMarkdown document, pdf output. I followed the suggestion described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962651/inserting-title-page-with-image-in-rmarkdown-to-render-a-pdf-document). My issue is that the blank page does not appear. Here is my code:

```
\pagenumbering{gobble} 

\centering
\centerline{\includegraphics[height=2in]{glasgowuni.png}}

\large{UNIVERSITY OF GLASGOW}

\normalsize{COLLEGE OF SCIENCE AND ENGINEERING}

\normalsize{SCHOOL OF MATHEMATICS AND STATISTICS}\linebreak

\raggedright

\clearpage

\pagenumbering{arabic} 

\tableofcontents

\newpage
```

Can anyone spot why the blank page does not appear?

Comment: Have you tried inserting a \clearpage before the \newpage ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding an invisible character and `\pagebreak` before the TOC:

```
&nbsp;

\pagebreak
```

This did the trick for me. Good luck with the thesis!

Answer (score 4):

I had to do it a little different (Using *bookdown*):

1. In the YAML header, set `toc: no`. Otherwise, we end up with two tocs.
2. Directly after the YAML header I needed to add the following code.

---

```
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\mbox{}
```

Comment: In case someone needs to keep the page numbers `\thispagestyle{plain}` will do the trick. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194423/page-style-plain-vs-empty) for more options.