# Add blank page after certain page in pdf Quarto

Tags: pdf, latex, quarto

I would like to add a blank page after certain page in pdf `Quarto`. I tried using `\newpage` like described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36880/insert-a-blank-page-after-current-page) with this reproducible example:

```
---
title: "Add blank page after certain page"
format: pdf
---

# Chapter 1

Here some random text

\newpage

\newpage

# Chapter 2

Again random rext after white page
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see in the output, there is no blank page after the first page. I also tried `\pagebreak` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097637/inserting-a-blank-page-after-a-title-page-in-rmarkdown), but that also doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to add a blank page between two chapters in pdf Quarto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add blank pages between chapters accounting for page numbers, we can follow [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374542/261065),

```
---
title: "Add blank page after certain page"
format:
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \usepackage{afterpage}
          \def\blankpage{%
          \clearpage%
          \thispagestyle{empty}%
          \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
          \null%
          \clearpage}
---

# Chapter 1

Here some random text

\blankpage

# Chapter 2

Again random rext after white page
```

---

[image: blank pages between chapters]

---

Answer (score 5):

If you choose a suitable class, your "chapters" will become actual chapters and not just sections and the class will take care of inserting empty pages so your chapters will always start on odd pages:

```
---
title: "Add blank page after certain page"
format: 
  pdf:
    documentclass: scrbook
---

# Chapter 1

Here some random text

# Chapter 2

Again random rext after white page
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me using [this accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34934/add-a-new-empty-page):

```
---
title: "Add blank page after certain page"
format:
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \newcommand*\NewPage{\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}
---

# Chapter 1

Here some random text

\NewPage

# Chapter 2

Again random rext after white page
```

Comment: please note that this approach will add counts for blank pages in the page numbers.

Comment: @shafee Traditionally blank pages between chapters should be counted. Otherwise the correspondence between even/odd numbers on left/right pages would randomly shift during a book.